# Add rewrite endpoint and .htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a redirection with .htaccess and rewrite endpoint (`add_rewrite_endpoint()`) and it's working but at the time of redirection it adds a /1/ to the route and I don't understand where it comes from. My htaccess rule:

Redirect 301 /wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/public/partials/informe.php /informe-calculadora/$1

The endpoint rewrite:

```
function add_virtual_page_template() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_endpoint('informe-calculadora', EP_ROOT );
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_virtual_page_template' );
```

The url i use:

```
https://xxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/public/partials/informe.php?email=asxxxxxsd@xxx.com&id=610
```

And the final url is:

```
https://xxxx.com/informe-calculadora/1/?email=asxxxxxsd@xxx.com&id=610
```

Why this /1/?

Excuse my poor english if wrong and thank you in advance.

Comment: "it adds a /1/" - Your `Redirect` directive ends with `/$1`? (The `$1` "backreference" makes no sense here.)

Comment: redirects and rewrites aren't the same thing. A redirect moves you from one URL to another, WP rewrite rules can't be used to move/redirect you. Rewrite rules can be used to map a URL or a URL regex on to specific query variables that determine what WP shows though. WP rewrite rules always rewrite pretty URLs into the form `index.php?queryvar=value` though, they cannot be used for arbitrary PHP files. Also you should **never** reference theme template PHP files in HTAccess or rewrite rules. WordPress loads and decides which theme template file to use, not the other way around

Comment: Perfect. Removing the $1 works perfectly. I had put it to collect the parameters but apart from being wrong it is not necessary. It works now. I understand the difference between rewrite and redirect. Those are the two things I need. One to clean the url and the other to redirect old web links (those with /wp-content/blablabla) to the new clean url. Thank you very much, it works now.

Comment: @JaviPs Glad it now works, you're welcome. I've padded out my comment as an answer, with some additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `https://xxxx.com/informe-calculadora/1/?email=asxxxxxsd@xxx.com&id=610`
>
> `Redirect 301 /wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/public/partials/informe.php /informe-calculadora/$1`

The `$1` "backreference" at the end of the target URL is in error (the `Redirect` directive does not support regex in which backreferences can be captured). This will likely be seen as literal text, which would explain the erroneous `1` at the end of the target URL (the `$` is likely being filtered out).

The additional trailing slash could result if you have an additional rule that forces trailing slashes (either in `.htaccess` or WordPress)?

> I had put it to collect the parameters but apart from being wrong it is not necessary.

Yes, any query string that is on the original request is passed through to the target by default. Unless you explicitly include a query string on the target URL.

However, since WordPress already uses mod_rewrite (for internally rewriting the request to the WP front-controller and other plugins are likely to do the same) then I would consider using mod_rewrite instead for this redirect, rather tan mod_alias (`Redirect`) in order to avoid potential conflicts.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/public/partials/informe\.php$ /informe-calculadora/ [R=301,L]
```

This would need to go *before* the WP code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker).

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser. For this reason it is always advisable to test first with 302 (temporary) redirects.